# Compass without eventListener

Tags: android, events, listener, compass-geolocation

When you normaly build an Compass app u use something like this:

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        int myAzimuth = Math.round(event.values[0]); //Angle

}
```

But I want to read the Data on my own something like: mSensorManager.getCompassAngle()

Is there a way without listener ?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, sorry -- `SensorManager` only works using a listener.